# Dynamic components based on route params in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is it possible in Vue to dynamically use components based on the value of a route parameter?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
path: '/model/:modelName',
components: {
  default: ModelDefinition.models.find((model) => model.key === $route.params.modelName),
},
```

The problem is: `$route` is not available here. Neither is `modelName`.

What might be nice if `default` could also be a function (similar to `props`):

```
path: '/model/:modelName',
components: {
  default: (modelName) => (ModelDefinition.models.find((model) => model.key === $route.params.modelName)),
},
```

This function actually gets called to my surprise, but the argument seems to be some sort of function, and certainly not the modelName I'm hoping for.

The reason I need this is: there's actually a lot more configuration for this route, specifying lots of components and values for various things. If I have to specify that for every model, it's going to be long and repetitive, and would have to be expanded for every model we add to our system.

Comment: How about route redirects using the [`beforeEnter`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) navigation guard (or the global one)?

Comment: That seems to be more for redirecting to other paths, like login, and not for deciding which component needs to be rendered where. Or do you have an example where it's used that way?

Comment: Well, it could be the latter one in some way, given the fact that [it's not yet created when the guard is called](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards). So passing the "target" route in the `next` callback would probably help in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you have to "do magic" with **vue-router** - why don't you just handle the parameter inside your component (or create a container-component, and handle the parameter there)?

The snippet below shows that you can use external data to control what component should be displayed. If you pass your **model** parameter down, then any existing (and registered) component-name can be displayed.

```js
const CompA = {
  template: `<div class="border-blue">COMP-A</div>`
}

const CompB = {
  template: `<div class="border-red">COMP-B</div>`
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    CompA,
    CompB
  },
  data: {
    selected: ''
  }
})
```

```css
[class^="border-"] {
  padding: 10px;
}

.border-blue {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.border-red {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option>CompA</option>
    <option>CompB</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
  <br />
  <br /> Here's a variable component - based on external data:
  <component :is="selected"></component>
</div>
```

Comment: This example doesn't use the router, but using a wrapper component that only interprets the route parameter and then loads the right component would probably work, yes. The only downside is that I'm going to end up with these container components everywhere. I was hoping to keep it all in one place: the router. But this will work. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can create this “container” as a mixin, and import it globally - it may be an ill-advised method, but technologically possible (it’s just a spontaneous idea, haven’t tested or thought it through)

Answer (score 1):

In `components` declaration, `this` is not available and hence you can not access the props and other instance data.

What you can do is create a computed property that returns a component. Like this:

```html
<template>
  <component :is="componentInstance" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    componentName: String,
  },
  computed: {
    componentInstance() {
      return () => import(`./modules/${this.componentName}/template.vue`);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```